# How to format a string to a proper url

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

On my login page I have a returnUrl query string parameter to bring you back to the page you wanted to visit before you were redirected to the login page.

I.e. http://localhost/login?returnUrl=//testsection/testpage

If the returnUrl has multiple slashes it will redirect to http://testsection/testpage instead of http://localhost/testsection/testpage

Is there a way I can take a string and format it to be valid?

Comment: you should encode url parameters values.

Comment: Just so you, we cannot access your local host. The clues in the same, it's hosted locally, just for you

Comment: Frankly, the problem here is the fact that your return value **has multiple slashes** at the start - it just: *shouldn't* - that is simply wrong. One slash: fine; multiple slashes: nonsense (unless you are trying to do a protocol-relative redirect to a different host). Once you have the right actual value - just use `HttpUtility.UrlEncode` and you're sorted.

Comment: A point to add on this - Make sure you validate the redirect Url so you know it's local, if you don't, you leave your site open to Unvalidated Redirect attacks. You can read up on them here : https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Unvalidated_Redirects_and_Forwards_Cheat_Sheet

Comment: I disagree with @Patrick's opinion that this is a duplicate of the linked question. I'm going to wave a "reopen vote" here, but unfortunately my votes are **all** binding, and that isn't my intention

Comment: To be clear: the query-string you want here is `?returnUrl=/testsection/testpage` - note no double-slash.

Comment: @MarcGravell Understood. In my scenario, my project is huge and has many places sending malformed url's to this page. Instead of trying to fix every instance and have them all QA tested, I'd rather make sure that what ever gets passed in gets formatted properly.

Comment: @user3953989 well, if a leading // is a common bug, I guess you could special case that in your code and change it to / **before** doing the redirect, but IMO the real solution here is to fix the offending code that is creating invalid data

Comment: @MarcGravell Total agreement in fixing the actual problem and not coding around the bug but QA won't be able to re-test all of these section and I will not get sign-off. Currently my only option is to go this route, the other issue is that it might be 4 leading slashes not just 2. I don't know what to expect from other areas of the code. I could use regex to just replace 1+n slashes with a single slash but that doesn't guarantee it will be a valid Url

Comment: @user3953989 well, to be clear: `//foo/bar` *is* a valid url in real terms - it is a protocol-relative link to `/bar` on the default port (for the protocol) of a host named `foo`; as for whether it is valid *to you*: that's for your "after login success" code

Comment: @MarcGravell Good point. I guess it's more how each browser deals with them. For now I created a method to use regex to fix multiple slashes and I'll just add more "fix" rules to that as I come across them.

Comment: @user3953989 well, not really; there's just "getting it right" and "doing it wrong"... `//foo/bar` has a single, well-defined meaning

Comment: @MarcGravell In my case, when using FF and calling Controller.Redirect("\\test\test") it treats my relative url as absolute but not in Chrome or IE.

Comment: @user3953989 and what happens if you get the slashes the right way around?

Comment: @MarcGravell Then it works in all browsers. I guess my question should have been, how to properly format a relative url

Answer (score 0):

after return url validation redirect with

```
Response.Redirect("http://" + (HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.Host + Request["returnUrl"]).Replace("//","/"));
```